# Can I receive a custom response from the WebClient function `onStatus(HttpStatus::is2xxSuccessful, ...)`?

Tags: spring-webflux, httpresponse, spring-webclient

Can I receive a custom response, say `Mono<MyResponseClass>`, from the `WebClient` function `onStatus(HttpStatus::is2xxSuccessful, ...)`?

I intend to:

- Send a POST request to a server API using WebClient.
- If the server API's response is in the `2xx` range, obtain a
  `Mono<MyResponseClass>` object.
- If the server API's response is not in the `2xx` range, obtain a `Mono`
  that indicates an error.

Here is my code:

```
Mono<MyResponseClass> responseMono = webClient.post()
    .uri(someServerApiUri)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .bodyValue(someRequestBody)
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is2xxSuccessful, clientResponse -> {
      //
      // I got this compiling error for the "return" statement:
      //     Required type: Mono <? extends Throwable>
      //     Provided: Mono<MyResponseClass>
      //     no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that MyResponseClass conforms to Throwable.
      //
      return clientResponse.bodyToMono(MyResponseClass.class);
    })
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> {
      return clientResponse.bodyToMono(someServerApiResponseErrorException.class)
          .flatMap(errorResponse -> Mono.error(new MyResponseErrorException(errorResponse.getMessage())));
    });
```

I believed the compilation error occurred because the `onStatus` function mandates its second parameter to be an `exception function` that returns a `Throwable`. However, `Mono<MyResponseClass>` is not a `Throwable`.

My question is: Is there any approach to return a `Mono<MyResponseClass>` object within the `onStatus(HttpStatus::is2xxSuccessful, ...)` function? I assume such a method should exist, as it seems logical to return the expected response when the HTTP status is 2xx. Requiring the second parameter to be an exception function when the HTTP status is 2xx does not appear to be reasonable.